# SVN - Restore history from a file after delete and recreate it

Tags: svn

I did some 'caca'. I had these:

```
x/perf/adm/a.xhtml
x/perf/adm/b.xhtml
x/perf/adm/c.xhtml
```

and when migrating these 3 files to x/adm/perf I deleted it after copy it at the new location.

Result: I lost their history. THEN I did the 'caca'. I created new files at x/perf/adm/ with the same name and content hoping to restore the history. But it seems that this doing overrided any trace of the old history.

Now it only shows the rev where I created these new ones.

Question: I still have some kind of their history by looking at 'x/perf/adm' history.

Is there anyway to retrieve their history from the folder's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the copy command to copy them back.  Like so:

```
svn cp x/perf/adm/a.xhtml@1234 x/perf/adm/a.xhtml
svn cp x/perf/adm/b.xhtml@1234 x/perf/adm/b.xhtml
svn cp x/perf/adm/c.xhtml@1234 x/perf/adm/c.xhtml
```

In this case 1234 should be the revision number that you want to copy from.  It should be 1 less than the revision that you deleted them.  So with the above you should have deleted them in revision 1235.

This technique is covered in the [Resurrecting Deleted Items section of the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect).

Comment: Though it didn't answer my question about how to restore the history that I had overrided with another file of same name, it was what i needed I managed to do so. Thanks

Comment: svn rm the file(s) before the copy.  That will replace the files with the old copy and your history will be fine.

Comment: Like "svn rm x/perf/adm/a.xhtml"? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes.  It's probably possible to skip that rm, but I don't do replacements often enough to remember if you need --force on cp or what to do a replacement of an existing versioned file.